# Basic Authentication not working even for correct credentials in IIS 7

Tags: iis

I am currently having a issue in basic authentication for a WCF service deployed on IIS.

When I browse the service i get a pop up window from the browser to give my credentials.Even if i am giving correct credentials , still i am getting the pop up again and again. Is it possible that the user id with which i am logging in is locked or something ?, because i was able to log in (several times) without problem earlier today.I also deliberately tried to login with wrong credentials which may have caused some problem i guess.

Any expert suggestion on this issue ? Thank You.

Comment: If the account you are using is locked this will happen. Have you checked the account status?

Comment: Can you please tell how to check account status for IIS ?

Comment: Your not checking IIS status.  You are checking the user account status. You'll have to look the user up in Active Directory to see if they are locked or not.  If it's a local account to the machine you are working on then look in computer management and the local users/groups.

Comment: My machine is Windows 7.There is no status mentioned for a user in Computer Management as far as IIS is concerned.The user is in administrator group.

Comment: Is the account you are using local to the computer or part of the network (Active Directory)?

Comment: it is local to the computer

Comment: What I mean by status: Go to computer management, open the local users & groups, then users and for that user in the list, right click and select properties.  In the general tab there is Account is Disabled and Account is locked out check boxes.  If either of those is selected for this account you'll need to uncheck it.

Comment: No,account is not locked or disabled.